# How to sort items in array in a particular order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Consider an array: `['wifi', 'food', 'water', 'shelter', 'jazz']`

How would one "sort" the array so that values that are more *important* than others (predetermined) appear first in the array?

Imagine the weights were:

`'wifi': 1
'food': 3
'shelter': 2
'water': 4
'jazz': 999`

If a value with no weights (eg. juice) came into the array, it would be pushed to the end.

So, the new array would be `['jazz', 'water', 'food', 'shelter', 'wifi', 'juice']`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (and get a badge). Your question lacks any attempt at solving this problem on your own. The idea is for you to try to get something to work and then come here with specific problems you are unable to resolve. Taking the tour and reading about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center will provide all the information you need.

Comment: With that said, let me add that arrays are not the best data structure for this. You are attempting to apply two dimensions to your data with a single-dimension data structure. This is simply and easily solved with key/value pairs that indicate the priority of each element and the element name - an object literal is the most efficient way to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Just sort your array based on your weights using `sort` and resort it after elements are added.

```js
let arr = ['wifi', 'food', 'water', 'shelter', 'jazz'];
let weights = {
  'wifi': 1,
  'food': 3,
  'shelter': 2,
  'water': 4,
  'jazz': 999
}

function order() {
  arr = arr.sort((a, b) => weights[b] - weights[a]);
}

function push(...elements) {
  arr.push(...elements);
  order();
}
order();


console.log(arr);
push('new');
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: And if we add say "automobile" with a weight of 2?

Comment: It sorts after shelter

Comment: 2 questions: 1) is that correct? 2) what does it take to implement that? 1) we have no idea because the OP has not given enough into, 2) Two structures must be synchronized and maintained (yikes).

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = ['zzzz', 'wifi', 'food', 'water', 'shelter', 'jazz', 'aaaaa', 'blah'];

let weights = {
  'wifi': 1,
  'food': 3,
  'shelter': 2,
  'water': 4,
  'jazz': 999,
  'blah': 2,
}

arr.sort((a, b) =>
    (weights[b] || 0) - (weights[a] || 0)
    || a.localeCompare(b));



console.log(arr);
```

`weights[a] || 0` returns the weight of the element, or a zero for an unweighted element. `|| localeCompare` sorts elements with equal weights (or no weight) alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this via making sure both values have a corresponding value in the object and then compare. If not just return -1 for the one which has and 0 for the other:

```js
let data = ['wifi', 'food', 'water', 'juice', 'shelter', 'jazz']
let weights = { 'wifi': 1, 'food': 3, 'shelter': 2, 'water': 4, 'jazz': 999 }

let result = data.sort((a,b) => (weights[b] && weights[a]) 
  ? weights[b] - weights[a] 
  : weights[a] ? -1 : 0 )
 
console.log(result)
```